# CSS three-column layout - clearing float

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why is this clear:both acting globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085100/why-is-this-clearboth-acting-globally)

I have three-column layout as an example on alistapart: http://www.alistapart.com/d/negativemargins/ex5.htm , but when I'm trying to make a box with  "clear: left" style: `<p style='clear:left;'>Lorem ... arcu.</p>`
the content below the box jumps under the left column. Screen: [bug demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsrYu.png) (chrome, firefox, ...).

What is the best way to fix it?

```
<h1>content</h1>
                <p style="float:left;">sdfsf</p>
<p style="clear:left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Phasellus varius eleifend tellus. Suspendisse potenti. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Nulla facilisi. Sed wisi lectus, placerat nec, mollis quis, posuere eget, arcu.</p>
```

Comment: Please add the code instead of an image

Comment: why would you want to clear the paragraph left? There's no other floats in that bounding box.. it doesn't make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to add "float: left" block's to #main block and I can't do clearint of the float. I added clear to the paragraph for the simple demonstration.

Comment: In the future don't edit and update your question with an answer. If you find the answer - actually post an answer to the question.

Comment: My reputaion is too low to post answer on own question, sorry

Comment: I'm gained 15 points of reputation and moved answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
#main {overflow: hidden;}
```

OR

```
#main {overflow: auto;}
```

Thanks to:
[Why is this clear:both acting globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085100/why-is-this-clearboth-acting-globally?rq=1)